# Positioning cursor before inserting building block and while avoiding page break afterwards

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a full-page Building Block I saved through the Building Blocks Organizer as name: "aWaiver" in my custom category: "Waivers" in the "Quick Parts" Gallery with Building Block Property: "insert content on its own page".

Two issues:
(1) I cannot seem to discover the proper "Selected.Range" VBA code to use to locate to the bottom of the current (last or only) page where I want to insert my aWaiver building block.
(2) When I manually locate to the bottom of my document and insert the aWaiver, it does begin its own page, but then inserts another following blank page.

Here is vba code I modified from the macro I recorded that seems to work albeit with the above issues.

````
        "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm"). _
        BuildingBlockEntries("aWaiver").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, _
        RichText:=True```
````

Comment: The page breaks are a function of the content in your building block and the settings of your new document. You may want to look at the vba on my page on Building Blocks: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock The code required depends on placement of the code and the building block.

Answer (score 1):

1. When writing VBA the `Selection` object is only used in exceptionally rare circumstances when it is unavoidable. To add your Building Block at the end of the document you can use `Where:=Document.Characters.Last`
2. The Building Block should be stored in your document template, not Normal.dotm, otherwise you will not be able to distribute it to other users.
3. The issues with the blank page are a result of the content that you have included in the Building Block.

Comment: 1. Wasn't sure if ```selection``` was the proper choice over ```range```. Seems to be a hot topic. I will do further research on the ```where:=``` Thanks for the strategy 2. Will delete and replace my building block 3. I am pretty sure my content is less than a page. I do have a footer in my containing page. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Footer has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I grabbing at (footer) straws because my content should not cause page overflow.

Comment: I suggest you invest some time in improving your Word skills. To do what you are attempting your skill level should be advanced user or above. You cannot hope to successfully automate software that you don’t have a thorough understanding of.

Comment: I see. I won't give up on my project, but I will refrain from any more postings.

Answer (score 1):

I’m reluctant to post given the recommendation that I gain Word literacy. But this post does appear in results for various key words in a Google Search. So, I will share my solution knowing that it lacks best practices.

At the end of my last paragraph in my prototype document I added a `bkPageBreakHere` bookmark. I then saved the selection in the Quick Parts gallery as a new Category `Waivers` as `aPartialWaiver` with Option `insert content only` (turns out that `insert content as its own page` does the page break after, not before)

Turning to the VBA Code, I found that Building Blocks did not automatically load with my module. So into the document I entered:

```
Private Sub Document_New()
'load Building Blocks
    Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks
'Present Waiver Form
    formCombined.Show

End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
'load Building Blocks
    Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks
'Present Waiver Form
    formCombined.Show
End Sub
```

Finally, in my form:

```
Private Sub CommandNext_Click()

                 ...
   Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="bkPageBreakHere"  'Position cursor
   Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak                       'Start new page                                           
'load next document
    Application.Templates( _
        "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\16\Building Blocks.dotx" _
        ).BuildingBlockEntries("aPartialWaiver").Insert Where:=Selection.range, _
        RichText:=True
                 ...
```

Issues remain. (1) Despite everything, I still get an empty page after my last legitimate one. (No, I do NOT execute the above code section on my last page.) (2) I get the “Security warning Macros have been disabled” when invoking the document from a template.

But all in all, the client is satisfied. I’ll continue my flailing to find a solution. Any thoughts welcome but not expected.